# JavaScript (React) How to get the contents of the error in try-catch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'd like to pick details from the thrown error and be able to use it. How do I 'read through' the caught error?

```
const submitRegister = async () => {         
        try {
            const data = await axios.post(apiurl, {email: email, password: password, auth: auth})
            console.log(data.data)
            navigation.navigate('LoginScreen')
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            setErrorMessage('Error 400. Display actual {data:{errormessage:xxx}} from response here')
        }
    }
```

Comment: [error properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#instance_properties)

Comment: Replace your other log with `console.error(error.message)` inside the `catch`.